# magento 1.9 Edit form is not displaying thumbnail image

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to display thumbnail image on EDIT form in Admin custom module.
I am getting check box  to delete image.
I am getting a square box where image supposed to display.
But it's not displaying image.

Please suggest me solution

my save() action in controller is

```html
public function saveAction()
    {
        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost())
        {
    if(isset($_FILES['shop_image']['name']) && $_FILES['shop_image']['name'] != '') 
    { 
     try {   
       /* Starting upload */   
       $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('shop_image');
  
       // Any extention would work
       $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
       $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
  
       
       $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
       
       echo $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'ud'.DS;
       
       
       
       $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['shop_image']['name'] );
  
      } catch (Exception $e) {
  
      }
        //  echo $path;exit;
      //this way the name is saved in DB

               $data['shop_image'] = $path.$_FILES['shop_image']['name'];
          }
    else if((isset($data['shop_image']['delete']) && $data['shop_image']['delete'] == 1)){
       .'ud'.DS.$data['shop_image']['value'];
      unlink($data['shop_image']['value']);
      //set path to null and save to database
      $data['shop_image'] = '';
     
      
    }
    $model = Mage::getModel('shop/shop');
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            if ($id) {
                $model->load($id);
            }
            $model->setData($data);
 
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
     
            try {
                if ($id) {
                    $model->setId($id);
                }
                $model->save();
 
                if (!$model->getId()) {
                    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('shop')->__('Error saving shop'));
                }
 
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('shop')->__('Shop was successfully saved.'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);
 
                // The following line decides if it is a "save" or "save and continue"
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));
                } else {
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                }
 
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                if ($model && $model->getId()) {
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));
                } else {
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                }
            }
 
            return;
  
           
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('shop')->__('No data found to save'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
```

my form.php is

```html
<?php
 
class Sample_Shop_Block_Adminhtml_Shop_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getExampleData())
        {
            $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getExamplelData();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getExampleData(null);
        }
        elseif (Mage::registry('example_data'))
        {
            $data = Mage::registry('example_data')->getData();
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array();
        }
 
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                'id' => 'edit_form',
                'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
                'method' => 'post',
                'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
        ));
 
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
 
        $this->setForm($form);
 
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('example_form', array(
             'legend' =>Mage::helper('shop')->__('Shop Information')
        ));
 
        $fieldset->addField('shopname', 'text', array(
             'label'     => Mage::helper('shop')->__('Shop Name'),
             'class'     => 'required-entry',
             'required'  => true,
             'name'      => 'shopname',
             'note'     => Mage::helper('shop')->__('The name of the shop.'),
        ));
 
        $fieldset->addField('logo', 'text', array(
             'label'     => Mage::helper('shop')->__('Logo'),
             'class'     => 'required-entry',
             'required'  => true,
             'name'      => 'logo',
        ));
 
        $fieldset->addField('productimage', 'text', array(
             'label'     => Mage::helper('shop')->__('Product Image'),
             'class'     => 'required-entry',
             'required'  => true,
             'name'      => 'productimage',
        ));
  
  $fieldset->addField('state', 'text', array(
             'label'     => Mage::helper('shop')->__('State'),
             'class'     => 'required-entry',
             'required'  => true,
             'name'      => 'state',
        ));
  
  $fieldset->addField('shop_image','image', array(
  'label' => Mage::helper('shop')->__('Shop Image'),
  'required' => false,
  'name' => 'shop_image', 
  ));
  
   


        $form->setValues($data);
 
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the below easy steps to display the thumbnail image.
Add this below code in your edit ->tab->form file
ex: Package_Campaign_Block_Adminhtml_Campaign_Edit_Tab_Form

```
$fieldset->addType('image','Package_Campaign_Block_Adminhtml_Campaign_Helper_Image');
```

Create the below helper class file to display the thumbnail image.

```
class Package_Campaign_Block_Adminhtml_Campaign_Edit_Tab_Form extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract{
    public function __construct($data) {
    parent::__construct($data);
    $this->setType('file');
}


public function getElementHtml() {
    $html = '';
    if ($this->getValue()) {           
        $media = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'campaign/';
        $html = '<a onclick="imagePreview(\''.$this->getHtmlId().'_image\'); return false;" href="'.$this->getValue().'"><img id="'.$this->getHtmlId().'_image" style="border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;" title="'.$this->getValue().'" src="'.$media.$this->getValue().'" alt="'.$this->getValue().'" width="30"></a> ';
    }
    $this->setClass('input-file');
    $html.= parent::getElementHtml();
    return $html;
} 
}
```

Comment: where to create this file?